# "Zipping" a plain list with a nested list

Tags: haskell

I am looking for an *elegant* solution to the following problem. I have two lists of the following types:

`[Float]` and, `[[Float]]`

The first list contains an *infinite* amount of random values. The second list contains values I no longer care about. Its structure is finite and must be preserved. The values of the first list needs to be replacing those of the second.

Obviously, since the first list contains random values, I do not want to use them twice. Can anyone help me do this in a *clear*, *concise*, and *terse* way?

```
scramble :: [Float] -> [[Float]] -> [[Float]]
```

Give me your best shot

Comment: Do you want to create a list with values from the first arguments and the structure of the second argument?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package for splitting:

```
import Data.List.Split (splitPlaces)
scramble x y = splitPlaces (map length y) x
```

Comment: @augustss: not one that is included with GHC

Comment: @newacct, even better then.  +1

Answer (score 8):

Will this do?

```
flip . (evalState .) . traverse . traverse . const . state $ head &&& tail
```

EDIT: let me expand on the construction...

The essential centre of it is `traverse . traverse`. If you stare at the problem with sufficiently poor spectacles, you can see that it's "do something with the elements of a container of containers". For that sort of thing, `traverse` (from `Data.Traversable`) is a very useful gadget (ok, I'm biased).

```
traverse :: (Traversable f, Applicative a) => (s -> a t) -> f s -> a (f t)
```

or, if I change to longer but more suggestive type variables

```
traverse :: (Traversable containerOf, Applicative doingSomethingToGet) =>
              (s -> doingSomethingToGet t) ->
              containerOf s -> doingSomethingToGet (containerOf t)
```

Crucially, `traverse` preserves the structure of the container it operates on, whatever that might be. If you view `traverse` as a higher-order function, you can see that it gives back an operator on containers whose type fits with the type of operators on elements it demands. That's to say `(traverse . traverse)` makes sense, and gives you structure-preserving operations on *two* layers of container.

```
traverse . traverse ::
  (Traversable g, Traversable f, Applicative a) => (s -> a t) -> g (f s) -> a (g (f t))
```

So we've got the key gadget for structure-preserving "do something" operations on lists of lists. The `length` and `splitAt` approach works fine for lists (the structure of a list is given by its length), but the essential characteristic of lists which enables that approach is already pretty much bottled by the `Traversable` class.

Now we need to figure out how to "do something". We want to replace the old elements with new things drawn successively from a supply stream. If we were allowed the side-effect of updating the supply, we could say what to do at each element: "return `head` of supply, updating supply with its `tail`". The `State s` monad (in `Control.Monad.State` which is an instance of `Applicative`, from `Control.Applicative`) lets us capture that idea. The type `State s a` represents computations which deliver a value of type `a` whilst mutating a state of type `s`. Typical such computations are made by this gadget.

```
state     :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
```

That's to say, given an initial state, just compute the value and the new state. In our case, `s` is a stream, `head` gets the value, `tail` gets the new state. The `&&&` operator (from `Control.Arrow`) is a nice way to glue two functions on the same data to get a function making a pair. So

```
head &&& tail :: [x] -> (x, [x])
```

which makes

```
state $ head &&& tail :: State [x] x
```

and thus

```
const . state $ head &&& tail :: u -> State [x] x
```

explains what to "do" with each element of the old container, namely ignore it and take a new element from the head of the supply stream.

Feeding that into `(traverse . traverse)` gives us a big mutatey traversal of type

```
f (g u) -> State [x] (f (g x))
```

where `f` and `g` are any `Traversable` structures (e.g. lists).

Now, to extract the function we want, taking the initial supply stream, we need to unpack the state-mutating computation as a function from initial state to final value. That's what this does:

```
evalState :: State s a -> s -> a
```

So we end up with something in

```
f (g u) -> [x] -> f (g x)
```

which had better get flipped if it's to match the original spec.

**tl;dr** The `State [x]` monad is a readymade tool for describing computations which read and update an input stream. The `Traversable` class captures a readymade notion of structure-preserving operation on containers. The rest is plumbing (and/or golf).

Comment: Slightly obfuscated for someone at my rudimentary level, nonetheless very elegant.

Comment: Nice thing about this solution is that it can work on deeper lists by adding more `traverse`.

Comment: Thanks. That's true. This thing really ain't fussy. It's perhaps a misleading coincidence that the original problem is taking from a list and making listy structures. If you want a nice generalisation, just strip it back to one traverse, so `(flip . (evalState .) . traverse . const . state $ head &&& tail)` which works for any `Traversable` structure, not just lists. `Traversable` is closed under composition `newtype C f g x = C (f (g x))` so you can use that fact to renegotiate two (or more) layers of container locally as one composite layer without changing the traversal machinery at all.

Comment: I like this solution because it is a generalization of the given problem.

Comment: You can tidy it quite a bit if you use the MonadRandom interface to manage your random number supply. Then you're looking at some wrapper for `traverse (const getRandom)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the obvious way to do it, but I take it this isn't terse enough?

```
scramble :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
scramble _  [] = []
scramble xs (y : ys) = some : scramble rest ys
  where (some, rest) = splitAt (length y) xs
```